# gdb: how does it know the variable type and size?

Tags: gdb, binutils

I'm trying to figure this out as I'm trying to do the same thing (hopefully) with a home grown script:

Example C code:

```
typedef struct _B
{
    A aa;
    double b;
    char c[LEN];
    int d;
    char *a_ptr[10];
 } B;

 B this_b;
```

If I compile this with `gcc -g` and `gdb a.out` afterwards, `gdb` knows exactly what and where `a_ptr` is:

```
(gdb) p &(this_b.a_ptr)
$1 = (char *(*)[10]) 0x804a084
```

how does it do that? And can I do the same thing (knowing it's address and type) through other utilities?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you inside your program want to access `a_ptr` then you just need to do &this_b.a_ptr just like in gdb. If you want to write a debugger on your own (or the equivalent code access), then I suggest you look at the gdb sources and figures out how it does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build with the `-g` flag, GCC (and most other compilers) stores additional "debugging info" in your binary (`a.out`).

You can examine that info with tools other than GDB. For example, `readelf -w a.out` (assuming you are on Linux or another `ELF` platform).

You can also compare the size of `a.out` when built with and without `-g`. It is not uncommon for the debug binary to be 5 to 10 times larger.

Answer (score 1):

This info is known on compile time. Gcc gathers it and stores it to be used later by different tools (gdb in this case).