# How does GDB know if a value is signed?

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb

I was curious how GDB determines whether a value is signed or unsigned. I have created a small program that stores a signed negative value into eax. I have run it through the debugger, and I noticed that it interprets the value at eax to be negative. How is this so? I have also tried this without generating debug info. Here is my short program:

```
section .text
global _start
_start:
    nop
    mov eax, [doubleWord]
    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
section .data
    doubleWord dd -52
```

Comment: Depends on how you print it. The `d` (decimal) and `f` (float) is signed, the rest, including `u` and `x` are unsigned.

Comment: You tell it how to interpret the value (there are no means to tell from the bits themselves).

Comment: dumb luck, what happens when you use an unsigned or a float, does it guess that right or just make it a decimal signed number? (my guess is the latter)

Comment: I'm working on something similar. So just to clarify, there is no way to deduce if a variable is signed or unsigned just by looking running some commands with GDB?

Answer (score 1):

For compiler-generated code, [debug info specifies the types for global symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496849/gdb-how-does-it-know-the-variable-type-and-size).

Without debug info, I think gdb just assumes everything is an `int`.

You *could* hand-code debug info yourself, but it's very cumbersome and usually easier to just override the types with casts or format specifiers for `p` and `x` commands.  (https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Data.html#Data)

For example, `p /x $eax` to print EAX as an (unsigned) hex integer.

Also, `layout reg` is nice.  See more asm debugging tips for `strace` and `gdb` at the bottom of the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried typing the hexadecimal value of EAX and it interpreted 0xffffffcc as -52. Also, ptype returned int_32, so it is handling the value as a signed integer.